# Getting Objects information

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the table and column information. So I wrote two queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Chag.sys.columns c
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id)='Aduser'

SELECT * FROM Chag.sys.tables so
WHERE so.name = 'Aduser' AND SCHEMA_NAME(so.schema_id) = 'Tref'
```

These two work fine when I execute them in Chag Database but when I execute this in different databse they return nothig.

I want to execute them in different database so how do i do that?

Comment: "but when I execute this in different databse they return nothing." - presumably because those objects don't exist in another database!

Comment: @MitchWheat I mean to say I want to get the table information of 'Aduser' table which exists in 'Chag' database from another database

Comment: peter: I have no idea what you are asking....

Comment: @MitchWheat I am using those queries in a stored procedure called table_info and the procedure exists in 'ChPoint' database so I when i execute the above queries in 'Chpoint' database they return nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`OBJECT_NAME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186301.aspx) function accepts an additional parameter of database ID. As for [`SCHEMA_NAME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175068.aspx), you should probably replace it with [`OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326599.aspx), which is equivalent to `SCHEMA_NAME()`, only it uses the object ID instead of schema ID and accepts the database ID too as the second (optional) parameter.

You can use [`DB_ID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186274.aspx) to get the ID of the specified database.

Here are modified versions of your statements:

```
SELECT *
FROM Chag.sys.columns c
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id, DB_ID('Chag'))='Aduser'

SELECT *
FROM Chag.sys.tables so
WHERE so.name = 'Aduser'
  AND OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(so.object_id, DB_ID('Chag')) = 'Tref'
```

Answer (score 2):

If the reason is in functions OBJECT_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME like Shark pointed out, then getting data from corresponding views instead of calling those functions may help:

```
select c.* from chag.sys.columns c
join chag.sys.objects o on 
    c.object_id = o.object_id
where o.name = 'Aduser'

select t.* from chag.sys.tables t
join chag.sys.schemas s on
    t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where t.name = 'Aduser' and s.name = 'Tref'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a `Database.Schema.Object` reference.  Try running this against other databases:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns c 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id)='Aduser' 

SELECT * FROM sys.tables so 
WHERE so.name = 'Aduser' AND SCHEMA_NAME(so.schema_id) = 'Tref'
```

Notice, though, that if there is no 'Aduser' or 'Tref' objects then you will not get results.

Comment: I mean to say I want to get the table information of 'Aduser' table which exists in 'Chag' database from another database

Comment: @peter Oh, that's because when you call `OBJECT_NAME()` and `SCHEMA_NAME()` in the context of another database, it references those Object IDs against the current database.

Comment: Is there a way to get around it?